# How do I load webpack resource in JSON

Tags: json, webpack

I have the following code...

```
[
    {
        "number": 0,
        "color":  "blue",
        "content": require('./first-card.pug')
    }
    ...
]
```

When I try to run Webpack I see...

```
ERROR in ./src/app/jg/cards/cards.json
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token r
    at Object.parse (native)
```

Do I need to escape or something?

Comment: What loader are you using to load cards.json? The json-loader?  Could you post your webpack.config?

Comment: I was using the JSON loader, I went down another path so I will have to redo the config but I will try to eventually. Basically though I did nothing more than make sure pug and json are in the resolve and that the JSON Loader and Pug Loader are configured for their respective extensions.